# Escaping characters in php, javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, escaping

I have a page where users are adding their reports at the end of day. They click the button "Add Report" and then it shows them textarea where they need to type a report. After they enter it and save it, i send that to database. But before writing in database i use this function to escape characters:

```
db::$conn->real_escape_string($str);
```

And report it saved successfully. When I open database table with MySQL Workbench, I see report in one row, and if it contains new lines it does not show but if i move my cursor over it it shows tooltip where new lines are present.

After that I need to show table of reports and enable editing. The problem is that when I click Edit button, it should show textarea and report in it, but instead i get empty textarea. I found the problem it is about escaping characters. This is how I render edit button in table.

```
$report = $row['user_report'];
$report = str_replace('"', '\"', $report);
$report = str_replace("'", "\'",$report);
$report = htmlspecialchars($report, ENT_QUOTES);
$r[] = '<a onclick="$(\'#editReport\').val(\''.$report.'\'); $(\'#editComment\').attr(\'onClick\', \'EditReport('.$row['id'].'); return;\');" class="btn-action glyphicons pencil btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-modal-ld"><i></i></a>';
```

$r[] is then atached to output data, but thing that most maters is this javascript. The problem is new lines, and I dont know how to escape them.
This is how it generates HTML page. Just to mention, if report is written without new lines everything works fine.

```
<a onclick="$('#editReport').val('Fixed bugs on \&quot;User report\&quot; page. 
Developing Transaction page.
Developing admin users page.'); $('#editComment').attr('onClick', 'EditReport(100); return;');" class="btn-action glyphicons pencil btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-modal-ld"><i></i></a>
```

And this new lines here are causing the problem.

The report that I entered is this one:

```
Fixed bugs on "User report" page. 
Developing Transaction page.
Developing admin users page.
```

But if i enter like this, it works:

```
Fixed bugs on "User report" page. Developing Transaction page. Developing admin users page.
```

EDIT:
I fixed it with another str_replace("\n", "\\n", $report);
it works for now :D

Answer (score 0):

That's bad. Consider instead using JavaScript to find the content and get its data, rather than duplicating your entire content into an inline event handler, because that's never going to work ;)

Comment: I thought about that way, but I am trying doing it this way now, and save that as last resort :D

Answer (score 0):

You should use `json_encode` function

Try this way

```
$report = json_encode($row['user_report']); // no need str_replace
```